# Ring of Sets in Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory, ring-theory, lebesgue-measure, semiring

I'm studying Measure Theory course in my faculty and a have an problem... 
If i have E, and E is a class of sets like E={A, B, H,...}.

When i can said that:
1- E is a Ring of Sets. 
2- E is a Semi-Ring of Sets. 
3- E is a Sigma-Ring of Sets.

In other way...
What is the definition and properties of the following: 
1- Ring of Sets.
2- Semi-Ring of Sets.
3- Sigma-Ring of Sets.

And what are the conditions that the ring and Semi-Ring are closed under it, i know that the ring of sets is closed under union and intersection.. But this true or not??

Finally, Which is the bigger between them, Is any ring is a Semi-Ring or, Any Semi-Ring is a Ring or WHAT??

Comment: I think that you cannot find information about these concepts because they classically have a different name: namely "algebra of sets", "semi-algebra of sets" and "sigma-algebra of sets". If you look up "sigma algebra" in Google you will find the definition.

Comment: If you have a problem in your course where a teacher asks you questions about things you don't even know the definition to, then you need to talk to your instructor. Either to find out where you are supposed to find the definition, or to get them for the first time. Failing that... just search the internet. You would have gotten plenty of answers with "ring semiring sigma measure theory" in your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case when looking for answers will work before asking questions. All three of these definitions even appear in Wikipedia (paraphrased slightly for consistency):

- Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a nonempty collection of sets. Then $\mathcal{R}$ is a [ring of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets) if:

  - $A\cup B \in \mathcal{R}$ if $A,B \in \mathcal{R}$
  - $A \setminus B \in \mathcal{R}$ if $A, B \in \mathcal{R}$
- Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a nonempty collection of sets. Then $\mathcal{R}$ is a [$\sigma$-ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-ring) if:

  - $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n} \in \mathcal{R}$ if $A_{n} \in \mathcal{R}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
  - $A \setminus B \in \mathcal{R}$ if $A, B \in \mathcal{R}$
- Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a nonempty collection of sets. Then $\mathcal{S}$ is a [semiring of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets#Related_structures) if:

  - $\emptyset \in \mathcal{S}$
  - $A \cap B \in \mathcal{S},$ if $A, B \in \mathcal{S}$
  - $A \setminus B = \bigcup_{i=1}^nC_i$ for some disjoint $ C_1,\dots,C_n \in \mathcal{S}$ if $A, B \in \mathcal{S}$

The terminology is meant to suggest that these "containments" are in order: $\sigma$-rings $\subseteq$ rings $\subseteq$ semirings

That $\sigma$-rings are rings is almost too trivial to talk about. The wiki page even gives you your answer that rings are semirings, albeit without explanation, not completely trivial, but still not hard. Just notice that $A\cap B=A\setminus (A\setminus B)$.

Comment: thank you for your answer,
i found in **Measure Theory(_PaulR. Halmos_)** ,
that the ring and semi-ring and sigma-ring contains the empty set..

secondly,
you said that semirings are rings, So is Any ring is semi-ring???

@rschwieb

Comment: @MinaSamirGerges Sorry, that was a typo. I meant what I said in the containment: rings are semirings. The hint I gave was correct, it was just those three words that were wrong way around.

Comment: @MinaSamirGerges In the first two, assuming that $\mathcal{R}$ is nonempty  and closed under complementation is enough to prove the emptyset is in the set already. So that is why the third one has the provision but the first two do not.

Comment: thank yo so much, you really help me :)
@rschwieb